# Meters to centimeters conversion program in C Language

Tags: c

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

char userInput;

int centimeter;
int meter;

float centimeterFloat = 0.0;
float meterFloat = 0.0;

printf("Enter c for centimeter to meter OR m for meter to centimeter:  ");
userInput = getchar();
//If the user types in 'm' or 'M' the progrsm will ask you to type in the length in meters and it will converts to centimeters.

if (userInput == 'M')
    userInput = 'm';
if (userInput == 'm')
{
//This calculation is to convert meters to centimeters.
    printf("\nEnter the length in meter:  ");
    scanf("%d", &meter);
    centimeterFloat
    = (meter * 100);
    printf("\nmeter\tcentimeter\n");
    printf("%d\t\t\t%4.0f\n", meter, centimeterFloat);
}
//If the user types in 'c' or 'C' the program will ask you to type in the length in centimeters and it will converts to meters.
if (userInput == 'C')
    userInput = 'c';
else if (userInput == 'c')
{
    printf("\nEnter the length in centimeter:  ");
    scanf("%d", &centimeter);
//This calculation is to convert centimeters to meters.
    meterFloat = (centimeter * 1/100);
    printf("\nmeter\tcentimeter\n");
    printf("%3.1f\t\t\t%d\n", meterFloat, centimeter);
}


return 0;
}
```

This is my code but when I put my input as decimals, the output does not come out properly please help and if I put 10cm the results of meters does not come out as decimal but 0 and one more question, how to make an exception handling program with if else statement? please help me thank you so much

Comment: Please indent your code before posting it to SO.

Answer (score 2):

One problem that I see is with your if, else if structure.

```
//If the user types in 'c' or 'C' the program will ask you to type in the length in centimeters and it will converts to meters.
if (userInput == 'C')
    userInput = 'c';
else if (userInput == 'c'){
    printf("\nEnter the length in centimeter:  ");
    ...
}
```

If the user enters 'C' the program sets the userInput, but then it won't get inside of the else if.  You could change the else if to an if.

```
if (userInput == 'C')
    userInput = 'c';
if (userInput == 'c'){
    printf("\nEnter the length in centimeter:  ");
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
meterFloat = (centimeter * 1/100);
```

to:

```
meterFloat = (centimeter * 1.0/100);
```

`centimeter`, `1` and `100` are all `int`s, resulting in integer multiplication and division.
Using integer division, `centimeter/100` is likely to be `0`, unless `centimeter` > `100`.

Comment: centimeter is an int as well though, so it is (int * int / int).  Its all interger operations. int * int produces int, / int produces another int.

Comment: @haccks wrong downvote! if `meterFloat` declared float then  writing `(centimeter * 1.0/100);` which make whole expression to float,  correct answer.

Comment: @haack we can also write as `(centimeter * 1f/100f);`

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
int centimeter;
int meter;
```

to

```
float centimeter;
float meter;
```

and  `%d` to `%f` in `scanf`
to input as decimal, because you are storing your input in `meter` and `centimeter`

Comment: Incomplete answer `scanf("%d", &meter);` ??  second need a cast here `(centimeter * 1/100);` or should like `(centimeter / 100);`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan; Oops!

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan; after declaring `centimeter` as `float`, I think no need of casting.

Comment: @hacacks yes correct so not need to add in answer but But I have impression that OP probably missing concept of integer division gives integer  as he is writing `1/100`